# Is it possible to add font awesome icons to whiwheel.js segments

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using `Winwheel.js` library to create a wheel. Now I want to change the style of the wheel segments. I want to add `FontAwesome` Icons to the segment with text. Is it possible?

I tried doing it this way `theWheel.segments[0].text="<span class='fas fa-viruses'> prize 1 </span>"` but didn't work

this is the link to the library [Winwheel.js](http://dougtesting.net/winwheel/examples/basic_code_wheel)

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Code Wheel</title>
        <script src='Winwheel.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id='canvas' width='880' height='300'>
            Canvas not supported, use another browser.
        </canvas>
        <script>
            let theWheel = new Winwheel({
                'numSegments'  : 8,         // Number of segments
                'outerRadius'  : 212,       // The size of the wheel.
                'centerX'      : 217,       // Used to position on the background correctly.
                'centerY'      : 219,
                'textFontSize' : 28,        // Font size.
                'segments'     :            // Definition of all the segments.
                [
                   {'fillStyle' : '#eae56f', 'text' : 'Prize 1'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#89f26e', 'text' : 'Prize 2'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#7de6ef', 'text' : 'Prize 3'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#e7706f', 'text' : 'Prize 4'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#eae56f', 'text' : 'Prize 5'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#89f26e', 'text' : 'Prize 6'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#7de6ef', 'text' : 'Prize 7'},
                   {'fillStyle' : '#e7706f', 'text' : 'Prize 8'}
                ],
                'animation' :               // Definition of the animation
                {
                    'type'     : 'spinToStop',
                    'duration' : 5,
                    'spins'    : 8,
                    'callbackFinished' : alertPrize
                }
            });
 
            // Called when the animation has finished.
            function alertPrize(indicatedSegment)
            {
                // Do basic alert of the segment text.
                alert("You have won " + indicatedSegment.text);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Technically, yes. After all, it's just javascript and you can rewrite it however you want. Winwheel.js doesn't natively support labeling with HTML which would be required for it to just work.

Comment: @Ouroborus how can I do it?